# Git ignore trailing whitespace in markdown files only

Tags: git, markdown, whitespace, trailing

I have a markdown file with lines that have trailing whitespace (which is correct and should be commited). I'm unable to add these changes using `git add -p` to the index because git complains about trailing whitespace. They are added correctly if I use `git add -A`, but I want it to work with `git add -p`.

I have in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
  whitespace = trailing-space,space-before-tab
```

This has been working fine since for the most part I DO want to warn on trailing whitespace (it is incorrect in HTML, JS and Ruby files).

How do I ignore the trailing whitespace in Markdown files only?

Answer (score 9):

In a `.gitattributes` file add the following:

```
*.md  -whitespace
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_checking_whitespace_errors

More specifically you could instead do the following:

```
*.md  whitespace=space-before-tab
```

(dropping the `trailing-space` for markdown files.)

Treat `.gitattributes` in the same way you do `.gitignore` and check it into the repo.

Comment: What does `**/*` mean?  `-whitespace` means "unset the `whitespace` attribute".

Comment: `**/` is a wildcard to match files in current folder and any descendants.

Comment: By the way, it's possible to add a global gitattributes file

“Attributes that should affect all repositories for a single user should be placed in a file specified by the core.attributesFile configuration option (see git-config[1]).”

Comment: `*.md` and `**/*.md` are equivalent for .gitattributes, because attributes only apply to files (not directories).

Comment: Using git version 2.34.1 the first suggestion (`-whitespace`) worked for me, but the second (`whitespace=space-before-tab`) did not.

Comment: `**/` is unnecessary and ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Use this in `.gitattributes`:

```
**/*.md text whitespace=-cr-at-eol,-trailing-space
```

`**/*.md  whitespace=space-before-tab` does not work. Try this in `cmd.exe`:

```
$ git config --show-origin --get core.whitespace
file:C:/Users/kevin/.gitconfig  trailing-space,space-before-tab,cr-at-eol

$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in trailing/.git/

$ cat > README.md
Trailing space here:
check it

$ git add README.md

$ git diff-index --check --cached 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
README.md:1: trailing whitespace.
+Trailing space here: 

$ echo **/*.md  -whitespace > .gitattributes

$ git check-attr --all -- README.md
README.md: whitespace: unset

$ git diff-index --check --cached 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904

$ echo **/*.md  whitespace=space-before-tab > .gitattributes

$ git check-attr --all -- README.md
README.md: whitespace: space-before-tab

$ git diff-index --check --cached 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
README.md:1: trailing whitespace.
+Trailing space here:

$ echo **/*.md text whitespace=-cr-at-eol,-trailing-space > .gitattributes

$ git diff-index --check --cached 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
```