# Apply Staged Changes to New Repo

Tags: windows, git

What mistake am I making in the steps I'm following?

I've edited files in repo `Alpha` on my local box.  I then realized I wanted those changes in a different repo `Bravo` that is also on my local box.  I tried this:

```
c:/repos/alpha/>git diff --cached > mypatch.txt
```

I then copy the patch file to the other repo location and type this:

```
c:/repos/bravo/>git apply mypatch.txt
```

If the shell I used for the diff and apply was powershell or "Git CMD", then the second command makes the error:

```
fatal: unrecognized input
```

If instead I use the "Git Bash" shell to execute the two commands, then I get a different error:

```
5109e.patch:19: trailing whitespace.
    IL.DataUsageGB,
warning: 1 line adds whitespace errors.
```

I then try to apply the changes more carefully with the following command:

```
$ git apply --reject --whitespace=fix mypatch.txt
```

From this I get a dump of numerous errors. Example:

```
error: while searching for:
);
GO
-- Anchor table ------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------
-- IL_InvoiceLine table (with 33 attributes)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------
IF Object_ID('dbo.IL_InvoiceLine', 'U') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IL_InvoiceLine] (

error: patch failed: scripts/bi/sql/Unified_ODS_Schema.sql:302
```

The branch in repo `Alpha` and the corresponding branch in repo `Bravo` both come from the same origin and both have a `git status` that report "up to date" with the upstream.  In other words, the branches are identical except for the staged changes that exist on `Alpha`.  I am expressly avoiding a push/pull with the origin.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

There's nothing wrong, and you can completely ignore the warning.  You don't need `--reject` or `--whitespace=fix`, but if you do want to use the latter, use it without the former.

#### Longer

> If the shell I used for the diff and apply was powershell ...

This winds up writing the output as Unicode (through some mechanism I cannot describe properly since I don't "do" Windows). You'd have to filter that back to UTF-8 or ASCII to get it to apply.

> If instead I use the "Git Bash" shell to execute the two commands, then I get a different error:
>
> ```
> 5109e.patch:19: trailing whitespace.
>     IL.DataUsageGB,
> warning: 1 line adds whitespace errors.
> ```

That's not really an *error*, that's a *warning*.  It means that your original patch adds a blank before an end-of-line.  By default, `git apply` *calls* this an "error" but it really means "warning".  It's meant to alert you to the fact that there's an invisible character on the line(s) in question, which you may not have intended.  (Or maybe you did!  For instance, in some Markdown formats, ending a line with *two* blanks inserts a paragraph break.  See aslo [Git ignore trailing whitespace in markdown files only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39752867/1256452).)

What constitutes a "whitespace error" (which really should be "whitespace annoyance" or "whitespace warning" or "whitespace glitch" everywhere, rather than "error") is configurable.  By default `git diff` will highlight such whitespace glitches.  While I cannot quite show it here, imagine the `-` line is in red and the `+` line is in green and that `<space>` represents a trailing blank:

```
- blah blah
+ blah foo blah<space>
```

This space would be highlighted in red, to make it stand out as a "whitespace error" (which I would call a whitespace glitch or annoyance or warning, but as long as we are using Git we should understand what the phrase "whitespace error" means here).

With `--whitespace=fix`, `git apply` will find the things it considers to be whitespace errors and determine whether it can fix them automatically by:

- stripping trailing whitespace
- removing some space-before-tab spaces
- fussing with CRLF vs LF-only

If it can fix them, it will.  This includes applying the patch even if the context does not quite match up but can be made to do so by this kind of fussing, so it's more than just "removing trailing whitespace in the added lines".

Comment: I removed the `--reject` flag and changed the whitespace flag to `nowarn`.  It then (seemingly) worked fine.